# Why does HBase use NavigableMap<Cell, Cell> to store Cell?

Tags: java, jvm, hbase

What's the point that makes key and value the same? Will the JVM optimize the memory and make them only one copy in heap?

Answer (score 2):

`Map<T, T>` is often used to implement a `Set<T>` with the same properties as a backing map. E.g. if a map is thread-safe, the corresponding set will be thread-safe, too. If a map is navigable, the set will be also navigable, etc.

Keeping an element in both key and value parts provides a way to get an exact instance stored in the set. Here are some typical use cases for this pattern.

- Obtaining a canonical object. Think of something like `String.intern()` but for arbitrary objects. Interning can be easily implemented with `Map<T, T>`:

  ```
  T existing = map.putIfAbsent(obj, obj);
  return existing != null ? existing : obj;
  ```
- Storing mutable objects in a set. If you want to modify an existing object, a set backed by `Map<T, T>` will come to the rescue again:

  ```
  T existing = map.get(key);
  if (existing != null) {
      existing.mutate();
  }
  ```

As far as I understand, a concurrent `NavigableMap<Cell, Cell>` is used in HBase to implement a concurrent navigable set of Cells with the above properties.

Note that key and value in such map are just two references to the same object. The object itself is not copied.